# When will the support period for sharepoint 2013 end?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I would like to know when will the support period for sharepoint 2013 end, we have a 2013 farm in production right now, and we are evaluating if it's worth upgrading to the 2016 version.

One of the important points to evaluate it's the support period for this product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies in the following link

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=sharepoint%202013

**Mainstream Support End Date:** 4th April 2018
**Extended Support End Date:** 11th April 2023

[image: SharePoint 2013 Support]